# как сбросить пароль биос через кнопку перезарузки на матери Asus. найдите пожалуйста ее

Tags: linux, windows, железо, bios, asus

достаточно ли простого отсоединения матери от батареи компьютера в данном случае?

[image: мать]

[[image: через A]

Comment: обычно надо отключить маленькую круглую батарейку

Comment: какую? где? я прикрепил фотографии. как видишь ее здесь нет, поэтому и прошу помочь

Comment: можете дать ответ основываясь на фотографии, чтобы решить конкретно мою проблему, пожалуйста. я второй день сбрасываю свой биос, теперь пробую новый способ

Comment: Не оно? https://dr-bios.com/threads/asus-x540bp-main-board-rev-2-0.32587/

Comment: Ещё https://badcaps.net/forum/showpost.php?p=1186960&postcount=23

Answer (score 0):

ASUS / Поддержка / FAQ / [Ноутбук/Десктоп/AIO]

[Забыт или утерян пароль BIOS (пароль безопасности)](https://www.asus.com/ru/support/FAQ/1046347)

---

> достаточно ли простого отсоединения матери от батареи компьютера в данном случае?

Как правило - недостаточно. В ноутбуках обычно используется микросхема CMOS со статической памятью, пока она сбросится по отсутствию питания - поседеешь.

---

Возможное решение - запись в микросхему CMOS, в общий блок, какой-нить голимой хрени (проще всего - попортить контрольную сумму основного блока). Тогда при загрузки ноут должен завопить о невалидных данных и сбросить настройки на дефолт. Впрочем, положительный результат и даже безопасность процедуры для работоспособности ноута - не гарантируются.